# Guarantees needed to read several bytes from file to struct

Tags: c++

I have a file that contains 7 bytes as little endian, where there is the following:

- 4 bytes for an int
- 2 bytes for an unsigned int16
- 1 byte for a char (signed)

Let's assume I have a struct :

```
struct A
{
int32_t a;
uint16_t b;
int8_t c;
}
```

What guarantees do I need on the compiler so that I'm ""alowed"" by the standard to just copy the memory from the file into the struct base adress, without reading member per member ?
Is being little endian and having sizeof(A) == 7 enough ?

Comment: i think here is your answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127246/copy-struct-to-struct-in-c/9127315

Comment: Padding could (almost certainly will) screw up that `sizeof(A) == 7` assumption.

Comment: Most compilers allow you to change the padding on a struct.  But it isn't standard.

Comment: Here is another question asking how to copy a character array to a struct that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621836/copying-array-to-a-structure  The answer to that questions answers your question really well.